# Testing differences between distribution

Tags: chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, multinomial-logit

I have a dataset that has 10 columns (which are nominal but contain data that is continuous) and 20 rows which are the discretized version of an age distribution (i.e., years). I want to test whether or not there is a difference between the columns (countries) across the ages. In other words, are the countries homogeneous in their columns (no country is statistically different from the others) or is there a difference between the columns. Since the ages are ordinal and the columns are nominal, people have suggested all types of methods (chi-sq, fisher exact, etc.) Getting the correct test is exceptionally important for what we are doing. I am open to any suggestions.